# Legacy Substance Material Detected (when using new versions of Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, legacy

I have open an old project in Unity 2018 and I got several problems.
The first one is this one

> Built-in support for Substance Designer materials has been removed from Unity. To continue using Substance Designer materials, you will need to install Allegorithmic's external importer from the Asset Store."

So I imported the new Substance plugin package from the Asset Store and saved the scene as mentioned 
[here](https://support.allegorithmic.com/documentation/integrations/upgrading-legacy-substance-materials-projects-170460267.html)

However now I have the following error: "Legacy Substance Material Detected: Assets/Materials/metal_hammered_steel.sbsar"

How do I properly update this so that it can work?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way at the moment to convert all materials. Allegorithmic is playing catch up with the Unity changes.

My workaround at the moment is to install substance [player](https://www.substance3d.com/products/substance-player). It has an export function. I have to set up my materials again in player, then export the textures in the size I need. I import them into unity and create a new Material. Then I assign the textures to the corresponding channel.

I know this is not a satisfying answer, but if you want to work with legacy substances at the moment, there seems to be no other way.